# Beaglebone java that displays to LCD cape (running ubuntu)

Tags: java, beagleboard, lcd

Hardware: Beaglebone + LCD cap

OS: Ubuntu 12.10

Problem: Basic java app that sets the background to a color - won't run from command line:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable....

How do I export DISPLAY so that my java app will access the LCD cape? (I presume that is the problem)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to at least invoke 'xhost +' from a terminal invoked in the graphical shell. There's probably some way to make that the default, but generally X11 disables access from other consoles that aren't the GUI login console until you invoke that command.

To get it to work at boot time, you can check out [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946770) or [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/setting-up-xauth-or-xhost-837610/). I think what would likely work best for you is to add to your .xinitrc file:

```
xhost +local:
```

Comment: Excellent - Thanks. Once doing that, it says it is 'unable to open DISPLAY ":0.0"' I've tried setting DISPLAY to many things, but with the same results.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm it at least works when invoked from a terminal running on the X11 console?

Comment: I've checked that the app works within Ubuntu full graphical version working on a laptop hardware platform (if that is what you mean - if not, how do I check?).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant add a USB keyboard/mouse combo, start a terminal under X and try invoking it there, right on your BeagleBone.

Comment: I get the feeling we're on to something: I'm not able to start X. As an ubuntu newbie, I've installed ubuntu-desktop, tried command line commands found on various sites (ALT-PRNTSCRN-K), startx, and others, but no commands found to launch the graphical desktop of ubuntu... Maybe it is the ubuntu version for beaglebone throwing me off.   Dare I ask 'how do I start X?'

Comment: Wow. X should start on its own. Which Ubuntu are you using? Are you using http://eLinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu.